# Reset SSRS Configuration to Default

Tags: reporting-services, active-directory, reset

I am looking for instructions to do a complete reset on my SSRS 2014 R2 back to the default configuration that comes out of the box.

I was trying to get domain passthrough authentication working.  The SSRS would prompt for a username and password.  I would enter the domain credentials and it would then display the reports home page.

In doing so, I did something and now it does not authenticate with the username and password anymore.

I am interested in a complete reset of all settings and starting from the beginning.  But I am not finding any place where those instructions exist.

Comment: I believe you can do a Repair through Programs and Features. Assuming you are on Windows.

Comment: My server is hosted in the AWS Cloud and I am not sure where the install media is located.